# what's the state of the process when it is multithread?

Tags: process, threads, multi-threaded

The state of a process is defined by the current activity of that process and is located in the PCB.

- new
- List item
- running
- waiting
- ready
- terminated

And a thread have its own state too, in the TCB.

So if the process is multithreaded, has more than one state or only one?

Comment: "if the process is multithreaded, has more than one state or only one?" Each thread will have its own status.

Comment: but, the process does not have its own state?

Comment: Yes. The process has one state and each of the threads has a state.

Comment: so... what is the process state, if for example, one thread is running and another is waiting?

Comment: I've no idea. That would depend on what operating system you are using and what thread libraries you are using.

Comment: Is this about Windows or Linux? Windows has a particular answer, but Linux may well be different.

Comment: In both cases, but if only windows has a answer, may be you can respond the question.